# How do I tell regex to match at least x number of alphanumeric?

Tags: php, regex

I have form where user submits field. Field can have letters, numbers, and punctuation. But I want to check to make sure that at least 3 of the characters are letters. How can I regex that?

For example,

```
$string = "ab'c";
```

And I need something like,

```
if (preg_match("/[a-z]{3}/i", $string))
    print "true";
else
    print "false";
```

That string has three letters, even though it has an apostrophe. It should test true. But for some reason, that tests false right now.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a case insensitive match on:

```
([a-z][^a-z]*){3}
```

Looks for 3 groups of a letter, and any number of non letters.

Comment: I think we have a winner! :D Thanks so much.

Comment: Might be slightly more efficient to make the `*` non-greedy... *shrugs*.

Comment: If performance mattered, a non-greedy quantifier would probably make thinks worse, not better.  A *possessive* one would definitely be more efficient -- `([a-z][^a-z]*+){3}` -- but we're talking about validating user input, so performance is not a legitimate concern.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You cannot write a regexp that checks for "at least x symbols of a class".</s> Of course you can

```
preg_match_all('~([a-z][^a-z]*){3}~', "ab'c")
```

In more complex cases, you can replace the class to something  else and then compare results (or simply use preg_replace fourth parameter):

```
preg_replace('~[a-z]~', '', "ab'c", -1, $count);
print_r($count); // prints "3"
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that a second ago. I can strip everything except letters, and then check string length to see if it's more than 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
^([0-9,]*[A-Za-z]){3}[A-Za-z0-9,]*$
```

You could also remove all non-letter characters and check the length:

```
if (strlen(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]+/', '', $str)) >= 3) {
    // $str contains at least three letters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
The `$` matches the end of the string ;)

```
if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z\']{3}$/i", $string))
    print "true";
else
    print "false";
```

---

Edit:
Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Try this:
`^([a-zA-Z\']{3,}(.?))$`

Results:
`hell'o` <-- true
`h31l0` <-- false
`hello` <-- true

Comment: I want it to test true if there are at least 3 letters. So all those cases of hell0 I would like to test true.

Comment: ? All you've done is sustitute both upper and lower for the original lower (which I'm pretty sure is already handled by the "/i" anyway). In any case, both "hell'o" and ""hell0" _satisfy_ the conditions.

Comment: @paxdiablo : No, i added the $ sign to match the end of the string.

@codemonkey: Oh, I think I mis understood your question, I thought you wanted to match 3 alphanumeric chars at the end of the string... Sorry for that.